# Difference between vouch and attest

Tags: difference

Is it correct that vouch is only to claim something true without proof, while attest is to prove something true?

Comment: A question like this one should at least include a couple dictionary definitions. Why? First of all, almost anyone who answers this question would want to see a dictionary definition to get underway; to send them all scrambling when you could easily do that for them doesn't seem like good etiquette. Secondly, it demonstrates that you've done a little legwork of your own, rather than use ELL to ask a question you're only curious about but haven't tried to research yourself. You can read more guidance [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Comment: then what is the difference between attest and prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the word 'vouch' does not necessarily mean the truth 'without proof'. It can also mean providing 'supporting evidence'. For instance, if you commit that you'll get an 'A' grade in an examination and then if you get it, I say *"Tim vouched his words by getting an 'A' grade."* On the other hand the word 'attest' is more reliable, firmer and authentic. You 'attest' the documents and signatures. You also confirm the event using the word; for instance, *"The weakness attested to his dehydration."*